# Use virtual pages point to one specific page

Tags: redirect, htaccess

**How should I approach this issue?**

**I want to create one page**, but many "*virtual* pages", e.g. like a productinfo.php. A product has several. In this case you manually create the posts in the database through dashboard and the virtual pages are pointing to specific posts in the WP database.

What I want is this is kind of same thing but **I don't want to add any posts and I want all virtual pages to redirect to same page with different GET request**:

Let met explain:

1. I create one page: e.g. cityinfo
2. If I go to /luton it should point to cityinfo?actualcity=Luton
3. If I go to /london it should point to cityinfo?actualcity=London
   etc.

Should I be using .htaccess for this? Or am I missing some easier/better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a rather easy way to achieve this:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'city/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$', 
'wp-content/plugins/csv-to-html/templates/csvtohtmlpage_core.php?city=$1' );
```

Yes, I know I did not mention city/ in the beginning but I just wanted wanted to know how should I achieve this. If someone has better ideas. Please tell me! :-)